# How does the correct rethrow code look like for this example

Tags: java, exception

Yesterday I red this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html) about the new Exception Handling in Java 7.

In the article they show an example (No 4) which is not working in Java 6. I just copied it.

```
public class ExampleExceptionRethrowInvalid {

public static void demoRethrow()throws IOException {
    try {

        // forcing an IOException here as an example,
        // normally some code could trigger this.
        throw new IOException("Error");
    }
    catch(Exception exception) {
        /*
         * Do some handling and then rethrow.
         */
        throw exception;
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {
        demoRethrow();
    }
    catch(IOException exception) {
        System.err.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Like in the article descriped it won't compile, because of the type missmatch -throws IOException- and -throw exception-. In Java 7 it will. So my question is.

How do I proper implement this kind of rethrowing of an exception in Java 6? I don't like the suggested implementation example no five. I know it is a matter of taste and problem you try to handle if unchecked exceptions or not. So what can I do to get the -throws IOException- and keep the stack trace? Should I only change the catch to IOException and risk not catching all?

I'm curious about your answers.

Comment: That smells like one hell of a typo. I think it should go like this at line 10 `catch(IOException exception) {`...otherwise this wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Bobby but then it would just work. I think it is not a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply catch `IOException`, like so:

```
public static void demoRethrow()throws IOException {
    try {
        // forcing an IOException here as an example,
        // normally some code could trigger this.
        throw new IOException("Error");
    }
    catch(IOException exception) {
        /*
         * Do some handling and then rethrow.
         */
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

If the code inside the `try` block can throw a checked exception other than `IOException`, the compiler will flag this up as an error, so you're not "risk[ing] not catching all".

If you're also interested in unchecked exceptions, you could also catch and re-throw [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) (you won't need to declare it in the `throws` clause).

Comment: I think your answer combined with the example from user470365 does its best for both checked and unchecked exceptions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Catch `IOException` and everything else separately:

```
public static void demoRethrow() throws IOException {
    try {
        throw new IOException("Error");
    }
    catch(IOException exception) {
        throw exception;
    }
    catch(Exception exception) {
        throw new IOException(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

catch(Exception ex) catches both checked and unchecked (RuntimeException) exceptions.
So to make it functionaly equivalent,

```
public static void demoRethrow() throws IOException {
try {
    throw new IOException("Error");
}
catch(IOException exception) {
    throw exception;
}
catch(RuntimeException exception) {
    throw new IOException(exception);
}
```

suffice, and compiler will detect other checked exceptions (good for thinking again about whether they should realy get this far, or should have bean delt with before)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way to throw to catch a generic exception and rethrow without the compiler checking the exception is to use stop.

```
public static void demoRethrow() throws IOException {
  try {
    throw new IOException("Error");

  } catch(Throwable t) {
    // handle exception

    // rethrow the exception without compiler checks.
    Thread.currentThread().stop(t);
  }
}
```